# Change Wordpress comments url / word

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, comments, comments-template

Is this possible? For example, I want to change

```
http://mysitesitesite.com/post-name/comment-page-1/#comment-452
```

to

```
http://mysitesitesite.com/post-name/custonname-1/#customname-452
```

What should I do to get it working? Is there any chance to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

In your functions.php add ( there are other rules relating to comment pages you can see them all with [Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/), this one just covers the case you mention )

```
add_rewrite_rule (
  '(.?.+?)/customname-([0-9]{1,})/?$', 
  'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]', 
  'top'
);
```

you'll also need to find in your theme ( possibly in your `function.php` ) where the comments are generated and change where the id is added to the comment html from something like ( if you can specify what theme your using can be more specific )

```
<li <?php comment_class('clearfix'); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
```

to

```
<li <?php comment_class('clearfix'); ?> id="customname-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
```