# How to change comment-page-1#comment-25 to any string?

Tags: comments, url-rewriting, slug, comment-form

How can we change the slug "`comment-page-1#comment-25`" to somthing like `review-page-1#review-25`

Comment: Already has an answer. Duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108926/change-wordpress-comments-url-word

Comment: hi @skribe i tried this solution without any success